# Galois theory for beginners, mistake?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I read this short article http://www.math.jhu.edu/~smahanta/Teaching/Spring10/Stillwell.pdf.
The goal of this article is to show the unsolvability of certain polynomials of degree $\geq 5$. But at the bottom of page 23 it says that any permutation $\sigma $ of $x_1,\dots , x_n$ extends to a permutation of $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\dots ,x_n)$ defined by

$$\sigma f(x_1,\dots ,x_n)=f(\sigma(x_1), \dots , \sigma(x_n))$$
for each rational $f$. I'm not convinced that this is well defined. In fact, I'd say it's not. For example, it could be that you divide by zero.

Is anyone willing to read the first two pages of this article and think about this claim? I have multiple issues with this definition and I believe it's just wrong, even if you would impose more conditions on it. The author of this article is a very good mathematician, so I do not rule out the option of me having some kind of brainfart and not understanding what he tries to explain.

Thank you in advance!

Edit: The $x_i$'s are roots of some fixed polynomial, not variables. You can read the first two pages (easy) of the article for the proper notations.

Comment: The $x_i$'s are roots of some fixed polynomial, the notation is introduced in the article.

Comment: Then if you want to be convinced, you can say that $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ so there is no division involved.

Comment: However, the author says that the paper deals with "the general $n$th degree equation". (See [here](https://books.google.ro/books?id=t6N_tOQhafoC&pg=PA308&lpg=PA308&dq=%22general+equation+of+degree+n%22&source=bl&ots=cSN7pqQ2Pj&sig=FLRBLbTLwE01uXnHsTdYZRlhWhU&hl=ro&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBl-b6j6jMAhVI3iwKHf-9C8IQ6AEIIDAC#v=onepage&q=%22general%20equation%20of%20degree%20n%22&f=false) to see what this means.)

Comment: @user26857: Thank you, I missed that word. Although, unless you already know what it is, this article doesn't make clear what the general $n$th degree equation is.

Comment: Well, I already knew what it was but apparently forgot it, I was trying to find a nice intuitive explanation for the unsolvability of some polynomials. Well anyhow, mistery solved. Thank you.

Comment: if I understood well, all this relies on the fact that $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are the roots of some irreducible polynomial $P(x)$ of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, hence $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \simeq  \mathbb{Q}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ where $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is a $n$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, which is also $\simeq \mathbb{Q}[x] / (P(x))$, and that permuting the roots lead to automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ (that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$) is then obvious.